# Do I have to send money to UK company as evidence of sufficient funds before being hired?

Tags: uk, proof-provenance-of-funds, scams

One company in UK send me message that i was qualified in the position they need. I was hired without an interview and they sent a contract letter, visa form, terms and condition and British ESF form.

Is sending money as evidence of sufficient fund is really needed or this is just a scam? Because they ask me to send money on western union and ask me to send the copy to them. Thank you

Comment: Sounds like a scam to me, what is the company called? No UK company would ever ask you for money hiring you.

Comment: Total scam.  No company ever asks you to pay to interview, *and nobody uses Western Union except to scam*.  The reason they want Western Union is that it's **irreversible** - there will be no way for you to get your money back.  Honest people use PayPal.

Comment: Scammity scam scam

Comment: @RLT They probably aren’t even in the UK, it’s easy for scammers to make emails and web pages look authentic

Comment: It's a scam for sure.

Comment: No real company will ever ask you for money to work for them. Never, ever. If they want money, it's a scam. If there was any cost involved (highly, highly unlikely) a real company would take that out of your first salary.

Comment: They ask me to send money to western union and ask my kjn family to send it and name after me as receiver. And told me to send them the receipt. So it is a scam?

Comment: This is 1000% scam. Don't give your money to them.

Comment: @RLT Absolutely, one hundred percent a scam. No real company would ever do this. Using Western Union is another very, very red flag because Western Union transfers money from A to B absolutely safely (which is good for the scammers), but there is no way on earth for A to get their money back if they are defrauded by B.

Answer (score 13):

This is undoubtedly a scam. It is illegal in the UK to ask job applicants to put money up front.

Did they ask you to send a picture of the western union receipt? They will use that to pick up your money from WU and you won't hear from them after that. (Or you will: see Patricia's comment below)

Comment: The OP may hear from them again. They may need cash for a deposit on an apartment rental. Pre-payment towards insurance on the car they will be providing. Payment for some sort of certification. Visa servicing fees. If the OP sends the money, they are likely to go on finding reasons to send more money until the OP refuses.

Comment: They told me to send money in western union. As for them this will serve as my evidence of sufficient funds. And ask me to send the receipt with them.

Comment: The company doesn't need evidence of sufficient funds. You might need to give evidence of sufficient funds for a visa to the UK govenment, but the evidence would be a copy of your bank statements, not a money transfer. Think about it: If you have £1000 in your bank account, and you send £1000 to me, then you just lost your funds.